# Using Defined Constants that will show up via autosuggest as Keys in a array

Tags: ios, objective-c, key, constants, nsuserdefaults

Was having trouble keeping track of my users NSUserDefualts, so I decided it makes sense to define a .h that will hold ALL my NSUserDefualts user_session vars that way there is never any confusion or any mistakes.Here was my attempt:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UserSessionConstants : NSObject

#define  user_device_udid @"user_device_udid";
#define  user_uid @"user_uid";
#define  user_full_name @"user_fullname";
#define  user_first_name @"user_first_name";
#define  user_last_name @"user_last_name";
#define  user_cover_photo @"user_cover_photo";
#define  user_default_photo @"user_default_photo";
#define  user_udid @"user_udid";


#define  user_isEmailConfirmed @"user_isEmailConfirmed";
#define  user_isCollegeActive @"user_isCollegeActive";



#define  user_draft_status_text @"session_draft_status_text";
#define  user_draft_image_url @"session_draft_image_url";
```

but, for some reason I get a error when trying to use any of these like so:

[image]

is there really no way to define a auto suggesting constant that is usable as a key? I have already tried extern, so far it has not worked for me and does not always autosuggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `;` in the end of all define.

Comment: Also realized that for some reason extern consts dont work if user_ is on the front of the name or  session_

Comment: Why are regular constants so unreliable w. autosuggest? its bizarre.

Comment: How are you define extern const? I just have used some your names and no errors occurred